# Redirect_to session_path controller and view RAILS DEVISE

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, redirect, view, controller

Why does this not work? I've tried multiple choices like render and puts, but it doesn't want to change properly. A couple of ideas users?

**THE VIEW:**

```
<div id = "container">
    <div id = "smaller-container">
    <%= user_signed_in? %>
  <%= @Uchecker %>
  <% else %>
     <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, :id => "SignUpText" %>
    </div>
```

**THE CONTROLLER:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def Uchecker
    @Uchecker = redirect_to user_session_path
 end
end
```

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what behaviour you're seeing and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, if user_signed_in? is true I want the Uchecker to redirect to the user_session_path, if not else Link to Sign Up text. That means that If a user is logged in redirect to "thisPage" when arriving at the ebsite.

Comment: First of all, you can't redirect to the user_session path.  That is the path that you post your credentials (email/password) to in order to create a new session.